# Iterate by a field in doctrine multiple result

Tags: php, doctrine

I have several values in my db and I want somehow to get the values grouped by a single column:

Example:

```
id  name       key value f_id
 1  a-name     a   1      1
 2  b-name     a   5      4
 3  c-name     b   7      2
```

So I want to have for key `a` also the values 1 and 5 and then for `b` the other one.
I've used:

```
return $this->repository->findAll();
```

But it just gives me the result for each row, I somehow want it grouped by key.

Comment: What is your expected result ? It's a bit unclear actually. You want to find the results only when `key == 'a'` ?

Comment: No, I want to get all the items from the table but for the same `key` to have them structured in the same object. f_id is a fk to another table so I want to also have the values from there.

Comment: But I am not sure how to fetch them in a single object/array let's say depending on the key.

Comment: something like `[ 'key' => 'a', 'values' => [ 1, 5 ] ]` ?